# Hibernate one-to-one mapping

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, nhibernate-mapping, hibernate-mapping

I'm facing a problem in hibernate one to one mapping. Googled a lot but unable to solve.

Here is database

[image]

**Following are my model classes**.

public class User {

```
private int userId;
private String userName;
private Address address;

public Address getAddress() {
    return address;
}
public void setAddress(Address address) {
    this.address = address;
}
public int getUserId() {
    return userId;
}
public void setUserId(int userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
}

public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}
public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}
```

}

and

public class Address {

```
private int addrId;
private String addr;

public int getAddrId() {
    return addrId;
}
public void setAddrId(int addrId) {
    this.addrId = addrId;
}
public String getAddr() {
    return addr;
}
public void setAddr(String addr) {
    this.addr = addr;
}
```

}

**user.hbm.xml** is as following:

```
<class name="User" table="users" schema="dbo" catalog="test">
      <id name="userId" type="int" column="userId" >
        <generator class="assigned"/>
      </id>
  
      <property name="userName">
         <column name="userName" />
      </property>
      
      <one-to-one name="address" property-ref="addrId"  class="Address" cascade="all" />

  </class>
```

address.hbm.xml is as below,

```
<class name="ammar.Address" table="Address" schema="dbo" catalog="test">

      <id name="addrId" type="int" column="AddrID" >
        <generator class="assigned"/>
      </id>
  
      <property name="addr">
         <column name="Addr" />
      </property>

  </class>
```

*On running, following exception occurs:*

Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to resolve property: addrId

Runs fine without mapping. But can't retrieve records when mapping applied.

***The query printed by hibernate runs perfectly fine in DB.***

Comment: You'll need to provide more details.  The getter and setter for addrId, the mapping file for Address, the sql structure for both.

Comment: I edited to provide details, as you said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In user.hbm.xml `property-ref="addrId"` should be `property-ref="userId"` because the property-ref is talking about how to connect an Address to a User, not the other way around, which is confusing.  You can probably leave out property-ref, since without it Address will find the User via the foreign key pointing at the primary key.  The [docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html) say "If not specified, the primary key of the associated class is used" (section 5.1.13).

Comment: I removed the property-ref attribute and it works. Thanx Jim.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's working with `int` values... I thing they have to be `Integer`...

can you change like this?:

```
private int addrId;
```

into

```
private Integer addrId;
```

and so on for all `int` variables...

Comment: The problem is not with int. It works fine when done alone with user or address. Problem is with mapping. i.e. here <one-to-one name="address" property-ref="addrId"  class="Address" cascade="all" />